# If $v_1 = 2v_1-3v_2 + 2v_3$ then ${v_1, v_2, v_3}$ is a linearly dependent amount.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

**Statement:**
If $v_1 = 2v_1-3v_2 + 2v_3$ then $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a linearly dependent amount.

**My question:**
Is this statement true or not?

**My answer:**
I guess it is linearly dependent amount due to that

$$v_1 = 2v_1-3v_2 + 2v_3\Rightarrow v_1-3v_2+2v_3=0$$ which is linearly dependent if $c_1v_1 +c_2v_2 +\ldots+c_pv_p =0$ if $c_i$ isn't equal to zero.

Am I thinking correct?

Comment: Yes. the vectors depend each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help